# Iterate Over JSON Object Obtained from Spring Boot Rest Application in Angular

Tags: json, angular, rest

I am getting a JSON response and I want to display the contents obtained from this response on my HTML page using angular.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.http.get(this.url)
       .subscribe(response =>{
     this.users = response.json();    
     });
}
```

Above code returns an Object of JSON which cause an error if iterated using ngFor.

I have tried some answers available on StackOverflow regarding this problem but they cause compilation errors or give no results.

Here is JSON Object I'm getting

```
{
   "_embedded" : {
       "users" : [ {
         "name" : "Ahmad",
         "role" : "Admin",
       "_links" : {
         "self" : {
         "href" : "http://localhost:8080/users/1"
       },
        "user" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8080/users/1"
      }
    }
  }, {
      "name" : "Umar",
       "role" : "User",
       "_links" : {
       "self" : {
       "href" : "http://localhost:8080/users/2"
     },
      "user" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/users/2"
    }
  }
  }, {
     "name" : "Ali",
     "role" : "Admin",
     "_links" : {
     "self" : {
       "href" : "http://localhost:8080/users/3"
     },
     "user" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/users/3"
    }
  }
}, {
  "name" : "Waqas",
  "role" : "User",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/users/4"
    },
    "user" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/users/4"
    }
  }
} ]
},
"_links" : {
  "self" : {
   "href" : "http://localhost:8080/users{?page,size,sort}",
   "templated" : true
  },
   "profile" : {
   "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile/users"
 },
  "search" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/users/search"
 }
},
  "page" : {
 "size" : 20,
 "totalElements" : 4,
 "totalPages" : 1,
 "number" : 0
```

}
  }

EDIT: HTML code with ngFor

```
<ul class="list-group">
   <li
      *ngFor="let user of users"
         class="list-group-item">

      {{ user }}

   </li>
```

I am learning angular at the moment so please give some explanation with the answer.

Comment: Share the html code where your are using ngFor

Comment: kindly see the edit part in question

Comment: https://www.chillyfacts.com/java-send-http-getpost-request-and-read-json-response/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify this

```
this.users = response.json();
```

to

```
this.users=response.json()._embedded.users
```

Comment: gives no output. Console shows this.users to be Undefined

Comment: this.users=response.json()._embedded.users . I get the correct output using this line. Thanks

Comment: Good to know. My bad I did not read your json correctly :) updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify this

```
this.users = response.json();
```

to

```
this.users = response.json()['_embedded']['users'];
```